# Adding Values to an Array and getting distinct values using Python

Tags: python, arcgis

I have python code below that will loop through a table and print out values within a particular column.  What is not shown is the form in which the user selects a Feature Layer.  Once the Feature Layer is selected a second Dropdown is populated with all the Column Headings for that Feature and the user chooses which Column they want to focus on.  Now within the python script, I simply print out each value within that column.  But I want to store each value in a List or Array and get Distinct values.  How can I do this in Python?

Also is there a more efficient way to loop through the table than to go row by row?  That is very slow for some reason.

many thanks

```
# Import system modules
import sys, string, os, arcgisscripting

# Create the Geoprocessor object
gp = arcgisscripting.create(9.3)
gp.AddToolbox("E:/Program Files (x86)/ArcGIS/ArcToolbox/Toolboxes/Data Management Tools.tbx")

# Declare our user input args
input_dataset = sys.argv[1] #This is the Feature Layer the User wants to Query against
Atts = sys.argv[2]          #This is the Column Name The User Selected

#Lets Loop through the rows to get values from a particular column          

fc = input_dataset

gp.AddMessage(Atts)

rows = gp.searchcursor(fc)
row = rows.next()
NewList = []

for row in gp.SearchCursor(fc):
    ##grab field values
    fcValue = fields.getvalue(Atts)
    NewList.add(fcValue)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store distinct values in a set:

```
>>> a = [ 1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4 ]
>>> b = set( a )
>>> b
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
>>> b.add( 5 )
>>> b
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
>>> b.add( 6 )
>>> b
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

Also you can make your loop more pythonic, although I'm not sure why you loop over the row to begin with (given that you are not using it):

```
for row in gp.searchcursor( fc ):
    ##grab field values
    fcValue = fields.getvalue(Atts)
    gp.AddMessage(fcValue)
```

And btw, `""" text """` is *not* a comment. Python only has single line comments starting with `#`.

Comment: Aye. Use `set` and you'll be all set. +1.

Comment: Hi poke, I changed my code to reflect your adjustments and I get an error.  Do you see any problems with it above?  Also I left out the set() for now until I get the loop working

Comment: What I was wondering is (a) why you iterate over `row`, (b) what `fields` is (as you didn't define it in the shown code, but I guessed it came from somewhere else) and (c) you might get problems now as you call `searchcursor` twice; it's possible that this conflicts, so better remove the first call.

Comment: BTW, it's OK to use `""" text """` to put comments in Python code -- not common, but it works and is one way to do multi-line comments. Since they are expressions, doing so might impact execution to some degree depending on where they're placed (although the optimizer probably gets rid of most of them).

Answer (score 1):

One way to get distinct values is to use a set to see if you've seen the value already, and display it only when it's a new value:

```
fcValues = set()
for row in gp.searchcursor(fc):
    ##grab field values
    fcValue = fields.getvalue(Atts)
    if fcValue not in fcValues:
        gp.AddMessage(fcValue)
    fcValues.add(fcValue)
```